# using a vector in a muti-threaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdvector

I've been puzzling over a problem with a multi-threaded application I'm writing.  Briefly, the main thread starts a hotloading thread that takes a list (vector) of file objects, checks their timestamps, and passes changed files to another vector.

The problem occurs when I attempt to add new files to the list of files that need to be checked.  The hotloading thread is continually checking the files in its list for changes, locking / unlocking a mutex with a scoped lock as it iterates.  Similarly, when the main thread calls the addItems() function, the same mutex is similarly locked, and new files are added.

The information I've read says this should be fine given the proper locking, and it does work, but I experience a very large slowdown as a result.  That is, if I add even one file to the list, the program continuously slows, as if the threads are becoming increasingly locked...

The code:

```
void MyThread::addItems( ItemList newItems )
{

   ScopedLock<Mutex> lock( itemMutex_ );


    for ( ItemList::iterator it = newItems.begin(); it != newItems.end(); ++it )
    {
        if ( ... test condition on (*it) ... )
            items_.push_back( (*it) );
    }
};

void MyThread::run()
{
    _done = false;
    do
    {
        YieldCurrentThread();

        if ( !isEmpty_ )
        {
            ScopedLock<Mutex> lock( itemMutex_ );
            for ( ItemList::iterator it = items_.begin(); it != items_.end(); ++it )
            {
                if ( ... test condition on (*it) ... )
                    updatedItems_.push_back( (*it) );
            }
         }
    }
}
```

The run() function, of course, runs continuously, iterating over my items_ vector, with the addItems() function called from another thread to insert items into the vector.  Only one thread calls addItems().

It can't be difficult, but I'm not seeing anything out there that hints at a solution I haven't already tried...

EDIT:

1. A comment below reminded me to point out that if I do not call addItems(), the run() function does not appear to have any significant impact on application performance, wasteful as it may be.

Comment: The way it is written, it looks like updatedItems_ would constantly be adding the same items from items_.

Comment: The addItems method isn't using the items parameter.  Did you intend to be iterating over that instead of items_?

Comment: Sorry, I redacted the code for easier reading.  On the addItems() function, I made typos.  They've been corrected.  Regarding updated items, there's a conditional test which indicates whether a file's timestamp has changed since it was last checked.  If so, it's pushed to the update list, which is then passed back to the main thread and cleared.

Answer (score 2):

What platform are you on?  If you are trying to watch for changed files, there are operating system facilities to do that efficiently for you.  On Linux that would be inotify.  If you're on Windows, this looks like a good article: http://qualapps.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html

Comment: Using Windows.  Trying to avoid OS-specific solutions, but in this case, I may be forced to it.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Sure.  There are a few well-debugged solutions to the problem it looks like you're trying to solve on Windows--you should embrace them.  Your issue is fundamentally not with mutexes and vectors, but with the actual processing you're doing (and probably don't need to do).

Comment: Good point.  I made an edit to my original post to address that (if I understand what you mean), but I'll definitely start looking at some other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your lock will spend very little time unlocked. Depending on the way `YieldCurrentThread` is implemented, I would expect the delay to be very brief, if indeed there is any delay at all. And the more things you have in your list, the longer on average that `addItems` will need to wait before it adds data to your vector. If your main thread is spending a lot of time calling `addItems`, I would definitely expect some slowdown.

One thing you can attempt is a thread loop that looks like this:

```
for (;;)
{
    ItemList snapshot;
    if ( !isEmpty_ )
    {
        ScopedLock<Mutex> lock( itemMutex_ );
        snapshot = items_;
    }
    ItemList updated;
    for ( ItemList::iterator it = snapshot.begin(); it != snapshot.end(); ++it )
    {
        if ( ... test condition on (*it) ... )
            updated.push_back( (*it) );
    }
    if ( !updated.empty() )
    {
        ScopedLock<Mutex> lock( itemMutex_ );
        updatedList_ = updated;
    }
}
```

The idea here is to take the heavy processing and move it out from under the mutex. Of course, this will only actually speed anything up if your actual bottleneck is lock contention. If the problem is just that more files take more time to check, then it's unrelated to the multiple threads.

Comment: I'm rarely adding files.  If I add even one file, it begins a cascading slowdown of the application - the amount of time it takes for control to return to the application increases significantly, and continues to do so without end.  It doesn't make sense that the iterative process is what's doing it.  Otherwise, +1 for a good optimization!

Comment: And nothing else touches the mutex? What about the code that reads `updatedList_`? If you're frequently polling that, you're repeatedly locking the mutex, and now your main thread and background thread are fighting each other.

Comment: Actually, I have a separate mutex for that, as I consider the updateList_ to be a separate resource.  I excluded it from here because my test was only with addItems().  Thus, in this case, the only place where resources are accessed outside this thread is in addItems().

Comment: And presumably you're only locking `updatedList_` from the background thread if there's actually anything to insert into it? If you keep it locked during the whole process of determining which objects are updated, you could get the same sort of slowdown.

Comment: Gotcha.  No, I don't lock the update mutex unless I need to make changes / read the updated list.  In my test, the update list code never actually runs, either.  I've stripped it down to the interaction between the push_back in addFiles() and the iteration of items_ in run().

Comment: I think you have something else going on that is semi-frequently locking the mutex from the main thread, but only if there's anything in the `items_` list, which is contending with the background thread. Either the version you've presented here is oversimplified, or it should be possible to make a minimal test case that demonstrates the dramatic slowdown.

Comment: You may be right.  I tried your optimization and it did improve performance (actually, quite significantly), but it's still pretty erratic.  It may be the API (which is high-performance) isn't liking what I'm up to.